# check list box rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checklistbox

I will have several checklist box in my project and all of them shall have the same behavior. How can I solve this so I don't need to add the following code for all CLB?

```
        private void clbFieldprob_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < clbFieldprob.Items.Count; ++ix)
                if (ix != e.Index) clbFieldprob.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
            clbFieldprob.ClearSelected();
        }
```

Comment: Create a custom UserControl for it, that wraps that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this.

```
private void demo_ItemCheck(Object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    var sd = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < sd.Items.Count; ++ix)
        if (ix != e.Index) sd.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
    sd.ClearSelected();
}
```

Then select the control and select in the lightning（Execute for each CLB）:

[image]

You can see three CLBs and three references in the demo.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it work well？